# Tomcat is slow on my VM, but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications

I have a webapp that was previously deployed like this on my VM :

- One War containing the core
- JAR of all Dependancies were given to Tomcat by adding them in CLASSPATH

=> My application took around 1 min to start

I am working on apply some "best practices" on that web app, and I firstly work on the dependency inclusion. Now the webapp looks like this :

- One War containing the core (WEB-INF/classes) and all dependencies (WEB-INF/lib)

In my Eclipse, there's no lag when starting the server, it takes around 2 mins. But on my VM, it now takes around 5 mins.

I would like to know if the old webapp deployment was a good practice ? And if it's normal to have that long startup time (for me).

Thanks.

Comment: If we know nothing about your machine specs, memory amount given to the servers.. etc. I guess it is impossible to tell you why.

Comment: In my world a minute is extremely long to start anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting Tomcat on a headless server, it can take a long time to gather enough entropy for the SecureRandom which generates sessionIds. This should however only affect startup.
You can read more about [How do I make Tomcat startup faster](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp) here.

Otherwise you have to look at the CPU and memory utilization, and enable Info/debug logging so you can see where Tomcat uses the time.

Answer (score 0):

In my Eclipse I modified eclipse.ini as
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

and In tomcat Attributes in eclipse I modified,
-Xms512m 
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:PermSize=1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

///My machine having 8GB of RAM